# mysql get whole word from string all words that have character in it

Tags: mysql, string

I have a table with a string field and I want to extract the first word that contains a '-'

if the field has "so I want to get th-is word" would return "th-is"

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is you should rely on your application code to parse this response, as Mysql does not have string functions built in that would handle this efficiently.

Another option is to create your own MySql function to handle this - this [link](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) may work as a tutorial for you.

Otherwise, here is a select statement that would do want you want - however I don't think I'd use it in production myself.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( "so I want to get th-is word", '-', 1 ), ' ', -1 ),
        '-',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( "so I want to get th-is word", '-', -1 ), ' ', 1 )
    ) AS returnstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to enclose the word that contains punctuation characters within `back-ticks`

"so I want to get `th-is` word" would generate "so I want to get th-is word"